# css text-shadow

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a `text-shadow` in CSS that is similar to the text-shadow created in Photoshop? I have tried, but the resulting shadow is still different than in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey no you can do this

```
.div{
box-shadow:0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1); //  outer shadow of box
box-shadow:0 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1) inset; // inner shadow of box
text-shadow:0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,1); // for text shadow 
}
```

more info click here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-text-shadow/

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is **no**.

Adobe Photoshop and all the different browsers interpret shadows differently from one another. You'll have to judge with your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
yourDiv
{
box-shadow: 8px 8px 5px #000000;
}
```

try different pixels according to the design, and as well as color, use color picker to check exact color code.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above its not at all possible. As browser renders the shadow differently than photoshop.